# How to darken an object face in a node group and make this optional

Tags: node-editor, shaders, groups

I am currently working on some virtual remotes for my home automation system.

This will involve images of remote buttons before and after pressing. To make it clear, I would like the face of the button to also be shaded darker when pressed.

I currently have a node group that combine a button texture with the operation icon and this takes as input the image of the operation (eg the Home icon) and the UV maps that separate out uv of the texture and the icon.

[image]

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. What can I do to simply add such shading (just darkening)
2. How can I make it so that this is passed in as an optional shading, thus allowing the node group to be used for standard buttons and the depressed shaded versions

Comment: You can add a *Mix (Color)* node and use the *Multiply* or *Darken* option to darken the material. The *Fac* input is your switch (0=normal, 1=darken).